# NPM-Failed to replace env in config: ${platform}

Tags: npm, npm-install, nvm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stoAz.png)
I use nvm and installed version 14.16.0 of npm. I switched to this version and tried to run 'npm i'. Then this error happened. Is that right to add 'platform' to the system environment variables of windows? But the colleagues' devices don't have this 'platform' in their system environment variables config and they don't have this problem.

I expect to run 'npm i' successfully.